# Stop page reload using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, frontend, web-frontend

I'm using JQuery and I need to stop page reload based on boolean flag value. Like this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    var reloadflag = false;  // reloadflag == false --> realod is not allowed

    if(flag == false)
       reload stop

});
```

`Reloadflag` will be updated dynamically. How can I stop reload? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking to show the prompt or not based on the flag? You can not stop the reload.

Comment: Try preventing the default action? `e.preventDefault()` Although you cannot truly stop it if a user continues the reload.

Comment: When user reloads page (for example using F5), I would ask user if his are sure. Using: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }); ` when user click F5, browser shows alert box (with a generic confirm message). I woud use a custom box and I would handle a relaod event.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can. The `'beforeunload'` event uses a native popup.

Comment: Using `beforeunload` and native popup, the client can block browser popup, so next time clients doesn't see popup.  Infact, I would use a custom modal window with confirm button but the problem is the same: Are there a way to stop reload event after F5 pressed? Using `e.preventDefault()` page is reload the same.  Thanks

Comment: No there isn't a way to prevent a user reloading or leaving a site (they're the same thing to JS). Thankfully, because this would allow a lot of abuse.

Comment: That was how adware used to keep you stuck on a site. That's why browsers no longer allow you to do this.

Comment: Ok, so I will use `beforeunload` event and default popup to avoid refresh page. If user disable popup from browser page will be refreshed. Thanks